# Exception thrown when trying to downgrade from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I had a WPF application which depends upon .NET framework 4.5. I am using MahApps.Metro and Some other libraries like System.Data.SQLite etc..
When i tried to downgrade  .NET framework version to 4.0, it throws
    
`FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, or one of
its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match 
the assembly reference.`

I am using VS2017 Everything was Just perfect before Downgrading

Comment: As you can see here: `Version=4.5.0.0`, you're still referencing .NET 4.5

Comment: I am relatively new to C#, how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, i figured it out,Just reinstalled all dependencies from NuGet  , thanks for help

Comment: Would you care to post an answer with the solution? So others with the same problem can use your Q&A as a referece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade all packages in NuGet to 4.0(Just reinstall them) and also some code removal trivial for .NET 4.5.
In my case i had to downgrade my own dlls to .NET 4.0